# Romex clamp need grounding in NMT?

Tags: electrical

I want to transition from Romex to THWN in PVC. The transition, from what I hear, is rather common from going from the inside to the outside. My question is, I know the NEC is pretty finicky when it comes to grounding anything metal in or on a electrical box, and I wondered if in the following situation, the romex clamp would have to be somehow grounded?

[image]

Note: the junction will be inside (attic).

Comment: If the box is inside, just use a metal box and connect that to the PVC, rather than using a PVC box... Probably/usually quite a bit cheaper.

Comment: I know you're just grabbing random images off the 'Net, but make sure you have the required cubic inches in the box.   Nice job on the graphic too, it gets your point across in a glance.

Answer (score 2):

### Use a plastic NM clamp

My solution to this problem would simply be to use a *plastic* (non-metallic, IOW) NM clamp, such as an Arlington NM74, NM75, or NM840-844, instead of the metal one, since this box is indoors.

Comment: interesting. but was more curious about the metal romex clamp where everything else is pvc wrt to grounding.

Comment: @Alex - What we are trying to say is that anything encasing or attached to an electrical circuit needs to be bonded to the grounding conductors. Otherwise there is a potential shock hazard. In the case of your metal conn. you can strip the ground wire all the way back and ensure that you are crimped or even attached to the screw for the bond. Or if you feel that is too awkward, install a metal box with a grounding lug. Good question, since no manufactured allowance is made for bonding a connector in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

No not at all never with that type of romex  fitting. Also with that fitting box has to be inside. Or mount to outside wall and uni bit a hole in box.